# Filezila Pro s3 Could not obtain a valid region

Tags: filezilla

I've followed the tutorial to connect to s3, obtained both keys but when I try to connect I get the following:

```
Error:  Could not obtain a valid region
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I've set the region to `us-east-2` not sure what else to do.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix will be available in the next version.
As a workaround restarting FileZilla Pro refreshes the S3 region configuration.

Answer (score -2):

When I updated to 3.54.2, I got the same problem.
I went to my previous version (3.52.0.5) and it's working fine.

Comment: This might be a valid response but I can't find a way to download an older version.